# warning C4305: инициализация: усечение из "double" в "float"

Tags: float, double

warning C4305: инициализация: усечение из "double" в "float" как исправить это предупреждение ? Нужна большая точность а это неявное преобразование типов как я понимаю мешает.Вот код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>


int main() {

    float startHeight;
    printf("Enter startHeight: ");
    scanf("%f", &startHeight);
    float g = 9.81;
    int t = 0;


    float currTime  = startHeight;
    int sec = 1;

    do {
        printf("t=%02dc  ", t);
        printf("%06.1f m\n", currTime);
        int sec = 1;
        clock_t endwait;
        endwait = clock() + sec *CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        while (clock()<endwait) {
        }

        t++;
        currTime = startHeight - (g*(t*t) / 2);
    } while (currTime >= 0);
    puts("BABAH!!!");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ругается скорее всего в этой строке

```
float g = 9.81;
```

все потому, что 9.81 считается типа double. Если нужен именно float (что бы убрать предупреждение), то пишите так

```
float g = 9.81f;
```

Но нужно помнить, что double имеет больше точность, чем float. Поэтому, Ваш комментарий **Нужна большая точность** немного смущает.

По факту, в этом примере кода, буква f ничего по факту не поменяет.